# Moving standard deviation with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a program that caches moving averages for a very large table into another table on a daily basis, the output looks like the table below:

```
date       AvgNet
---------- ----------------------
2014-05-12 116.553598762874
2014-05-13 116.672864387303
2014-05-14 116.141278835128
2014-05-15 118.067104561961
2014-05-16 117.92175621176
2014-05-19 117.056031596087
```

How can I calculate a moving standard deviation (that is, standard deviation over the past x number of rows for each date) on the above table using SQL?

I have seen window function and CTE solutions to moving average, but from what I understand, these solutions cannot be made applicable to standard deviation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server has the `stdev()` function.  However, it does not do cumulative standard deviations, so you need to use a correlated subquery or `cross apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.stdev10 
from table t outer apply
     (select stdev(t2.avgnet) as stdev10
      from (select top 10 avgnet
            from table t2
            where t2.date <= t.date
            order by t2.date desc
           ) t2
      ) t2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this query but am not getting the expected result. After day 10, all standard deviations are the same? Here is an sql fiddle to demonstrate. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9b25/2/0

Comment: @phosplait . . . That' s because I left out an all-important `order by`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon, should have caught that one. I think this accomplishes what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you're on SQL2008. If ever you get to SQL2012 or higher, the following works well enough.

```
SELECT  * ,
        STDEV(avgnet) 
           OVER ( 
              ORDER BY date 
              ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
           ) AS s
FROM    dbo.TestData
```

Comment: Good to point out, as I think this has a slight performance advantage. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on 2008 for a while.